# MERN stack Forget Password doesn't work on frontend (Postman works perfectly fine)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux

**MERN stack Forget Password doesn't work on frontend (Postman works perfectly fine).**
**when put the email and click the send button then showing this error - user not found**
**I'm trying but I can't solve the problem. Please give me some advice.**

**userController.js**

```
const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/errorHandler");
const catchAsyncErrors = require("../middleware/catchAsyncError");
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const sendEmail = require("../utils/sendMail")

exports.forgotPassword = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});

  if (!user) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("User not found", 404));
  }

  const resetToken = user.getResetPasswordToken();

  await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

  const resetPasswordUrl =`${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/api/v1/password/reset/${resetToken}`;

  const message = `Your password reset token is :- \n\n ${resetPasswordUrl} \n\nIf you have not requested this email then, please ignore it.`;

  try {
    await sendEmail({
      email: user.email,
      subject: `Ecommerce Password Recovery`,
      message,
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: `Email sent to ${user.email} successfully`,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
    user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;

    await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

    return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
  }
});
```

**userRoute.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const {forgotPassword} = require("../controllers/userController");
router.route("/password/forgot").post(forgotPassword);
```

**app.js**

```
const user = require('./routes/userRoute');
app.use('/api/v1',user);
```

**userConstant.js**

```
export const FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST = "FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST";
export const FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS = "FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS";
export const FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL = "FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL";
export const CLEAR_ERRORS ="CLEAR_ERRORS";
```

**userReducer.js**

```
import {
    FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
    FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS,
    FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL,
    CLEAR_ERRORS
  } from "../constants/userConstant";
 export const forgotPasswordReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true,
          error: null,
        };
      case FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          message: action.payload,
        };
      case FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.payload,
        };
  
      case CLEAR_ERRORS:
        return {
          ...state,
          error: null,
        };
  
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

**userAction.js**

```
import {
    FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
    FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS,
    FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL,
    CLEAR_ERRORS
  } from "../constants/userConstant";
export const forgotPassword = (email) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/v1/password/forgot`, email);

    dispatch({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, payload: data.message });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
```

**ForgotPassword.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./ForgetPassword.css";
import Loader from "../Loader/Loader";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { clearErrors, forgotPassword } from "../../actions/userAction";

const ForgetPassword = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { error, message, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.forgotPassword
  );

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const forgotPasswordSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const myForm = new FormData();

    myForm.set("email", email);
    dispatch(forgotPassword(myForm));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
    if (message) {
      alert(message);
    }
  }, [dispatch, error, message]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <div className="forgotPasswordContainer">

              <form className="forgotPasswordForm" onSubmit={forgotPasswordSubmit}>
              <h2 className="forgotPasswordHeading">Forgot Password</h2>
                <input className="inputsignforgot" type="email" placeholder="Email" required name="email"
                  value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" className="forgotPasswordBtn" />
              </form>

        
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ForgetPassword;
```

**App.js**

```
import ForgotPassword from './components/Users/ForgotPassword';
<Route path='/password/forgot' exact element={<ForgotPassword/>} />
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be dispatch(forgotPassword(email)); instead of dispatch(forgotPassword(myForm)); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `dispatch` call to accept the email as a parameter in `ForgotPassword` (as @AndrewAllison suggested):

```
const forgotPasswordSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  dispatch(forgotPassword(email));
};
```

Also, change your `axios` call to send the body parameter as an object:

```
export const forgotPassword = (email) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST });

    // Send body param as object
    const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/v1/password/forgot`, { email });

    dispatch({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, payload: data.message });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
```